# Looping a ZSH shell script with loop variables in awk

Tags: shell, awk, zsh

```
last.xyz contains the following list of co-ordinates
C 0.1 0.1 0.2
H 0.2 0.2 0.3
N 0.3 0.4 0.5
C 1.5 2.2 3.4
```

and so on.

I want to  print a sequence of files

```
2ndmoleculeShift0.1.xyz 
2ndmoleculeShift0.2.xyz 
2ndmoleculeShift0.3.xyz
```

and so on where my 2nd column increments by 0.1, 0.2, 0.3 and so on.

This is the code I tried

```
#!/bin/zsh     
for i in {'0.1'..'10'}
do
    awk '{print $1 "  "$2+$i "  " $3 " " $4}' last.xyz > '2ndmoleculeShift'$i'.xyz'

done
```

However, It failed. It gave an ouput with file name '2ndmoleculeShift0.1..10.xyz'

What is wrong with this code?

My script should essentially do the following

```
for i in 0.1 to 10
    awk '{print $1 " " $2+$i " "$3 " "$4}' last.xyz > 2ndmoleculeShift$i.xyz
```

The required output is

```
    2ndmoleculeShift0.1.xyz
    C 0.2 0.1 0.2
    H 0.3 0.2 0.3
    N 0.4 0.4 0.5
    C 1.6 2.2 3.4

    2ndmoleculeShift0.2.xyz
    C 0.3 0.1 0.2
    H 0.4 0.2 0.3
    N 0.5 0.4 0.5
    C 1.7 2.2 3.4
```

and so on

Comment: @EdMorton   I updated the explanation in the question

Comment: @EdMorton I simplified the question and the contents of last.xyz

Comment: @EdMorton updated the explaination of  error in the question and added the required output file contents

Comment: Looks like you changed your requirements and got rid of the "shifted" output file and the original "PC-PC.xyz" input file after I posted an answer. Something to bear in mind is that any time you write a shell loop just to manipulate text you have the wrong approach. The guys who invented shell also invented awk for shell to call to do text processing so just call awk.

Comment: @EdMorton point noted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's still not clear to me but I THINK what you're trying to do is something like this:

```
awk '
BEGIN{ ARGV[ARGC] = ARGV[ARGC-1]; ARGC++ }
NR == FNR { a[NR%58] = $0; numLines++; next }
FNR == (numLines-58) {
    for (i=0.1; i<=10; i+=0.1) {
        print a[FNR%58] > ("shifted" i ".xyz")
    }
}
FNR > (numLines-58) {
    for (i=0.1; i<=10; i+=0.1) {
        str = $1 "  " $2+i "  " $3 " " $4 
        print str > ("2ndmoleculeShift" i ".xyz")
        print str > ("shifted" i ".xyz")
    }
}
' "PC-PC.xyz"
```

Comment: This script works perfectly. What I was trying to do is something similar